# How to attach "slide" & "slid" events to the Bootstrap toolkit's carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a fiddle with a working Bootstrap carousel.
http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/5TDff/

And here's the official documentation which tells nothing about event usage.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

I thought this would work but no:

```
     $('#carousel').bind('slide',function(){
            alert("Slide Event");
    });
```

Comment: Please +1 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20792

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on your fiddle `#carousel` is wrong. It should be `#myCarousel`.

Updated Example:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
});

// Could be slid or slide (slide happens before animation, slid happens after)
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
    alert("Slide Event");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/wPF3n/

With Bootstrap 3

http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/wPF3n/252/

Comment: Any help why i get an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ' when i add this on my code?

Comment: For anyone getting here looking for help with BootStrap 3, try this instead:
`$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  alert("Slide Event");
})`

Comment: @c0r3yz The existing seems to work fine with bootstrap 3 for me, is there something specific that changed?

Comment: @Gary.S -- Not sure what changed, is just wasn't working for me in BS3

Answer (score 8):

For ***Bootstrap 3*** implementations :

**Before event**

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
       console.log('before');
});
```

**After event**

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
       console.log('after');
});
```

Comment: @ManicDepression they are not `slid` vs `slide`

Comment: @CsabaToth.. try fetching the index of active indicator.. I did something like this, works for me -
    $(".carousel-indicators li.active").data('slide-to');

You might want to check your indicators

Comment: @T.Adak Yes, we can work it around with weight lifting, but it'd be just nicer to get it straight from the framework

Comment: Oh, looks like there's a PR for https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21668 woohoo

Answer (score 1):

Old post I know, but I wanted to show both slide and slid using the .on function.

So, my 2 cents...
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/droidsignage/9fwuq/1465/)

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $( '.carousel' ).removeClass('color-start');
    $( '.carousel' ).addClass('color-finish');
    $('#bind').html('Sliding!');
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $( '.carousel' ).removeClass('color-finish');
    $( '.carousel' ).addClass('color-start');
    $('#bind').html('slid again!');
});
```

The 'addClass & removeClass' are for the fun of showing something is happening and when. Also, you could use this along with animate.css to add/remove the 'animated' class to elements .on(slide,).

```
$('#bind').html('Sliding!')
```

The above is I don't like 'alerts' and showing console.log can be a pain on smaller screens.