# Bootstrap carousel pagination / slide numbering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I, like many others, want clickable and styleable pagination to run with the Bootstrap carousel so i don't have to run additional jquery plugins (eg. innerfade) over the top of bootstrap.

I've had a shot using this question (and answer) [Bootstrap Carousel Number active icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499154/bootstrap-carousel-number-active-icon) but so far no dice, I can't see what i'm doing wrong here.

Here's my fiddling http://jsfiddle.net/adriatiq/V4SBt/ (strangely the pagination works in the fiddle and not locally). As you can see, numbering doesn't skip through as the slides progress.

Please excuse my woeful js skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked into your code. I've added the class based on clicking on the 1,2,3 numbers...
But I was unable to do the same for next prev links...

http://jsfiddle.net/V4SBt/1/

I've written the code but its commented... In that code I've getting strange error saying Undefined click event on those link when I tried to listen to those click event.

Comment: Thanks Vins, It seems to be working okay both on the fiddle and locally. I'm trying to find that error in the inspector but i'm rubbish at js debugging.

Comment: You can debug your javascripts by using Google chrome press ctrl + Shift + i, then navigate to console to see the errors. And on firefox you can install firebug for js debugging.

Answer (score 6):

This one works for me :)
http://jsfiddle.net/4WY6S/6/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var currentPage =0;
 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
         interval: 7000
     })
 $('#carousel-nav a').click(function(q){
    q.preventDefault();
    clickedPage = $(this).attr('data-to')-1;
    currentPage = clickedPage-1;
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(clickedPage);
    });
var pages = $("#carousel-nav a");
var pagesCount = pages.length;
$('#myCarousel').on('slide', function(evt) {
  $(pages).removeClass("active");
  currentPage++;
  currentPage=(currentPage%pagesCount);
  $(pages[currentPage]).addClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

Here is the code for the "Prev" and "Next" buttons:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(currentPage>0){currentPage=((currentPage-2)%3);$('#myCarousel').carousel(currentPage+1);}">PREVIOUS</a> | <a href="#" onclick="if(currentPage<2){$('#myCarousel').carousel(currentPage+1);}">NEXT</a>
```