# Twitter Bootstrap carousel indicators hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When hover Twitter Bootstrap carousel indicators then active the associated carousel item? How i do this?

Thanks advanced

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: No I'm not tried something @SidM

Answer (score 1):

The code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519603/3421811 should help you

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
    // Get currently selected item
    var item = $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item.active');

    // Deactivate all nav links
    $('#carousel-nav a').removeClass('active');

    // Index is 1-based, use this to activate the nav link based on slide
    var index = item.index() + 1;
    $('#carousel-nav a:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

you can diy your css

Comment: Now when you click then active carousel item. I want when you hover indicator then active carousel item? How i do this?